# Goldwasser-Micali variation

Tags: quadratic-residuosity

I try to create a valid decryption function for a modified the Goldwasser-Micali scheme

$pk = (N,p,q)$ where N is a Blum-Number $(p = q = 3 \bmod 4)$

$Enc_{pk}(m) = (-1)^{m} \cdot r^{2} \bmod N \text{  where  }  r \in_{R} \mathbb{Z}^{*}_{N}$

Now when I want to decrypt a ciphertext I can check if $m = 0$ by checking if $c \in QR_{N}$ because
$$
c = (-1)^{0} \cdot r^{2} \bmod N = 1 \cdot r^{2} \bmod N
$$

but when $m = 1$ then we got
$$
c = -1 \cdot r^{2} \bmod N
$$
now the Law of quadratic reciprocity states

> The first supplement to the law of quadratic reciprocity is that if p ≡ 1 (mod 4) then −1 is a quadratic residue modulo p, and if p ≡ 3 (mod 4) then −1 is a nonresidue modulo p.

so we know $c \in QNR_{N}$ but for Goldwasser-Micali I need $c \in QNR^{+1}_{N}$ is there a way to proof that in this case  $c$ has the Jacobi symbol $+1$ ? Or is this the wrong direction?

Comment: Can you, given the information that N is a Blum number, calculate the Legendre symbol of -1 modulo p and modulo q respectively?